# Local Extension Updates not appearing

Tags: extension

How do I make my extension recognise that there is an update available locally?

I have updated the info file, added a function (upgrade 2020) and cleared cache, logged in and out, clicked the refresh button on the extensions page etc.

I've established that even on uninstall and reinstall there is no entry in the civicrm setting table for this extension along the lines of:
| 89 | Extension  | org.civicoop.civirules:version            | s:4:"1005"; |         1 |       NULL |         1 |         NULL | 2016-03-19 04:28:15 |        203 |

Update:
When I go onto the extensions page I encounter:
When I go onto the extensions page now I encounter:

Recoverable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to CRM_Admin_Page_Extensions::createExtendedInfo() must be an instance of CRM_Extension_Info, null given, called in /var/www/html/civi46/drupal-7.39/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Admin/Form/Extensions.php on line 75 and defined in CRM_Admin_Page_Extensions::createExtendedInfo() (line 297 of /var/www/html/civi46/drupal-7.39/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Admin/Page/Extensions.php).

The key variable that it creates the extended info parameter from is null as well. Any ideas?

All suggestions welcome!

Thanks,

JohnFF

Answer (score 0):

For the "CRM_Admin_Page_Extensions::createExtendedInfo() must be an instance of CRM_Extension_Info, null given" error: if you cannot get rid of it by clearing the cache and you are sure your extension itself is correct then it can be that the Extensions page is locked in an update.

In this case you can temporary unlock it by commenting and forcing a disabled message

```
//if (!CRM_Extension_System::singleton()->getBrowser()->isEnabled()) {
  CRM_Core_Error::statusBounce(ts('The system administrator has disabled this feature.'));
//}
```

then you can get back the admin/extensions page and refresh it.